# VBA - Applying Autofill with inserted rows (based on input box) and apply it to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba, rows, autofill

I have a macro that add news rows based on a input userbox and I'd like to use the autofill to keep the formulas and also same layout if possible.

Example: I want to add 4 extra products in sheet1. Now, the macro (my button) creates 4 new rows below row #24 (Product1), row #28, and row #32. I want to apply the original formulas in columns O, AB, AO, BB and BO to the new inserted rows. How can I adapt the following code?

```
Sub NewPoS()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim MyN As String
Dim i As Long, MyMarker As Long, MyM As Long, LstRW As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Feuil1

MyN = InputBox("Give me a number", "My Input Box")
If Not IsNumeric(MyN) Then Exit Sub
MyN = CInt(MyN)
For MyMarker = 1 To 5
LstRW = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MyM = Application.Match("Marker" & MyMarker, ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(LstRW, 1)), 0)
    For i = 1 To MyN
        ws.Rows(MyM + 2).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlUp
    Next i
Next MyMarker

End Sub
```

Besides, I want to do the exact same thing on sheet2, but in which values of cells are the same as sheet1 (as already set)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1) you wrote _"creates 4 new rows below row #24 (Product1), row #28, and row #32"_, i.e. below three rows, while as per your code its should create rows below five rows (`For MyMarker = 1 To 5`). 2) why are you inserting rows from the third row below the found ones (`ws.Rows(MyM + 2).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlUp`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy all the formulas that you already have in 1 row you can use this command:

```
secondRange.Formula = firstRange.Formula
```

Where secondRange and firstRange are both range objects. So for instance if you have all the formulas that you want in the first row in your worksheet you can assign the first range to a range object:

```
Dim firstRange As Range
Set firstRange = Range("A1:BO1")
```

Then inside your loop where you create the new row, paste in the formulas:

```
For i = 1 To MyN
    ws.Rows(MyM + 2).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlUp
    Range("A" & (MyN + 2) & ":BO" & (MyN + 2)).Formula = firstRange.Formula
Next i
```

Or if you want to get the formulas one at a time you can do that too. It's a similar command, but instead of range2.Formula = range1.Formula you do it one cell at a time, like

```
Cells(MyN + 2, 15).Formula = Cells(1, 15).Formula
```

For the second sheet it's the same thing. You can create a second loop to insert all the values in the second sheet, just make sure that you reference the sheet name or index number each time you reference a cell or range.

```
For i = 1 To MyN
    Sheets(2).Rows(MyM + 2).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlUp
    Sheets(2).Range("A" & (MyN + 2) & ":BO" & (MyN + 2)).Formula = firstRange.Formula
Next i

Sheets(2).Cells(MyN + 2, 15).Formula = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 15).Formula
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. It seems to have a problem in this line Set firstRange = Range("A1:BO"). It says error 1004, Method range of object 'Global' failed.

Comment: In my case, first row that has the formula is #24 (Range could be then Range("A24:B024"), if I put that, no error but it doesn't copy the formula

Comment: That's probably because I forgot to include the row number for column BO. I'll edit that. As to why it's not copying the formula for you I'm not sure, maybe if you post your new code...